# "K" engraved on cube cracks with Bevel modifier

Tags: modifiers, bevel

Hello i have a file attached at https://pasteall.org/blend/a98056a67ac44c44a31606c55252f763 where i have created 3 cubes each with letters N,Z, and K engraved on them. N and Z work perfectly fine with the bevel modifier and i have checked and made sure the geometry of each cube is perfect with no duplicate edges, vertices, faces but i cannot for the life of me figure out why the K cube cracks with a bevel modifier and also it doesn't bevel as smooth as N and Z which also have acute angles. Any idea what is going on?

[image]

Comment: Please add a closer view of the exact geometry around the crack, and maybe also one around similar areas on the other letters for reference.

Comment: @TheLabCat: If you would have opened the blend file you would have seen that it is not the geometry, but face orientation...

Comment: @Chris I wasn’t exactly in a position to open the Blend file at the time. But I meant to ask: how did you show the face orientation in the new file? I’ve never quite figured out how to do that.

Comment: @TheLabCat: i am not sure whether i understood you right, but you can see face orientation here:[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0KBS.png -> viewport overlays -> check "face orientation"

Comment: @Chris i experimented deleting and adding faces and i'm still curious though how it was possible for the face to be inverted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your "K" has wrong face direction:

[image]

So select your K, then TAB -> edit mode, then Mesh -> Normals -> Recalculate outside

[image]

Comment: wow nice! thank you very much! i just learned something new from this. so i saw this video that explained it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=clzstqtN6YQ but i don't understand how is it possible that it got flipped?

Comment: glad i could help